# Referencing in enumitem list levels

Tags: cross-referencing, enumitem

The following defines my enumeration parameters:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                               Enumeration Parameters
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlist[enumerate]{labelsep=*}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{labelindent=1em, itemsep=12pt, label=\bfseries\arabic*., ref={\bfseries\arabic*.}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{leftmargin=*, itemsep=10pt, label={\bfseries(\emph{\alph*})},ref={\bfseries\theenumi(\emph{\alph*})}}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{leftmargin=*, topsep=10pt, itemsep=10pt, label={\bfseries(\emph{\roman*})}, ref={\bfseries\theenumii(\emph{\roman*})}}
```

What I am interested is in coming up with a dynamic referencing set-up that will reference normal outside the enumerate environment as shown in the MWE below in the line

```
Normal referencing: \ref{st1} and \ref{st2} and \ref{st3} work fine.
```

but also references differently within the enumerate. The image explains what am looking for.

[image]

Here is MWE that shows the issue:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                               Enumeration Parameters
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlist[enumerate]{labelsep=*}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{labelindent=1em, itemsep=12pt, label=\bfseries\arabic*., ref={\bfseries\arabic*.}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{leftmargin=*, itemsep=10pt, label={\bfseries(\emph{\alph*})},ref={\bfseries\theenumi(\emph{\alph*})}}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{leftmargin=*, topsep=10pt, itemsep=10pt, label={\bfseries(\emph{\roman*})}, ref={\bfseries\theenumii(\emph{\roman*})}}

\begin{document}
\noindent 
Here is a MWE of the list set-up above.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Sample Text 1 \label{st1}. With level 2 referencing the same thing appears: \ref{st2}. I would prefer just \textbf{(\textit{a})} unless I specify a particular item in level 3 then something like \textbf{(\emph{a})(\emph{i})} would be better.
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Sample Text 2 \label{st2} with reference level 3 is not appealing as shown here: \ref{st3}. I would prefer something like \textbf{(\emph{i})}. 
                    \begin{enumerate}
                        \item Sample Text 3 \label{st3}
                    \end{enumerate}
            \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
Normal referencing: \ref{st1} and \ref{st2} and \ref{st3} work fine.
\end{document}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.